# Python TKinter: using Entry within multiple Frames

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to have a Main Frame which offers various options. Each option goes to different function which opens a new Frame and runs a routine which gets an input from the user using Entry and Get. My problem is that while everything else works, I'm not able to obtain the value (val) that was input. Here is a shortened version of the software:

```
# ================================
#Python 3
# ================================
def FnFrm2():
    Frm2.tkraise()

    Lbl_Frm2 = tk.Label(Frm2,text="Frame 2")
    Lbl_Frm2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W', ipady=15)
    Lbl_val = tk.Label(Frm2,text="Enter text: ")
    Lbl_val.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W', ipady=5)    
    Ent_val = tk.Entry(Frm2, width=10) 
    Ent_val.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W', ipady=5) 
    val= Ent_val.get()   
    print(val)

    Btn_Frm2 = tk.Button( Frm2, text = "Enter", command = FnEnter)
    Btn_Frm2.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=5)
 
    print(val)
    Lbl_1 = tk.Label(Frm2,text = "value: ")
    Lbl_1.grid(row=2,column=0)
    Lbl_2 = tk.Label(Frm2,text=val, relief="sunken", width=10, padx=5, pady=5)
    Lbl_2.grid(row=2,column=1) 
    
# ================================
def FnEnter():
    print("Button pressed")

# ================================
# MAIN
# ================================

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x300")
FrmMain = Frame(root)
Frm2 = Frame(root)
FrmMain.tkraise()

for frame in (FrmMain, Frm2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

Lbl0 = tk.Label(FrmMain,text="What do you want to do?")
Lbl0.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W', ipady=15)

Btn1 = Button( FrmMain, text = "GO", command = FnFrm2)
Btn1.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='E', padx=10, pady=5)
Lbl1 = tk.Label(FrmMain, text="Goto Frame 2")
Lbl1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='W')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to call `.get()` on the Entry *later*, after the user has actually typed something into it - rather than a millisecond after creating the Entry.  Inside `FnEnter()` would be a good place to do this.

Comment: That works, thanks! I just had to  make Ent_val global in FnFrm2 and put Ent_val.get()  in FnEnter().

def FnEnter():
    val= Ent_val.get()   
    print(val)
    print("Button pressed")